# React native: transparent view inside opaque view

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I want to show view from camera with opaque frame and transparent center. Something like in the picture (black part is a view from camera). I'm looking for solution with pure react-native components, no additional libs (like https://github.com/gilbox/react-native-masked-view), without adding fullscreen image with transparent center or other hacks.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I found simple solution, I added `View`, transparent inside with opaque border, something like this:

```
let {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
<View
  style={{

    position: 'absolute',
    top: -width/2 + 100,
    left: -width/2 + 50,
    right: -width/2 + 50,
    bottom: -width/2 + 200,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',

    borderWidth: width/2,
    borderRadius: width,
    borderColor: 'red',
    opacity: 0.3,
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work like I want. it show transparent border with a red center.

Comment: To get a transparent center and opaque borders you can use this: `<View style={{position: 'absolute', alignSelf: 'center', width: (width*2.5), height: (width*2.5), left:-(width*0.75), top:-(width*width/height), borderWidth: width, borderRadius: width*1.02, borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'}} />`

Comment: @Sami too large size can make bad performance though