# Create a transparent circle on top of an Overlay in react-native

Tags: background, react-native

[image]

Source: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView
By checking source code, it has some `png`.

Setting a backgroundColor `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)` and creating a circle view on top of this simply doesn't work.

How do I create an Overlay like this in react-native?

Answer (score 10):

## Solution 1:

You can use [react-native-hole-view](https://github.com/ibitcy/react-native-hole-view) package to achieve this type of hole

```
import { RNHoleView } from 'react-native-hole-view';

<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
  <Text style={{ flexGrow: 0, flex: 0, padding: 10 }}>{"Wow! I'm a text inside a hole!"}</Text>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}} style={{ backgroundColor: 'pink', padding: 10, borderRadius: 5 }}>
    <Text>{"Wow! I'm a button inside a hole!"}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <ScrollView style={{ flexGrow: 0, flex: 0, padding: 10 }} horizontal={true}>
    <Text numberOfLines={1}>
      {
        "Wow! I'm a ScrollView inside a hole! Wow! I'm a ScrollView inside a hole! Wow! I'm a ScrollView inside a hole!"
      }
    </Text>
  </ScrollView>
  <RNHoleView
    style={{ position: 'absolute', width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(34,146,231,0.4)' }}
    holes={[{ x: 150, y: 390, width: 120, height: 120, borderRadius: 60 }]}>
  </RNHoleView>
</View>
```

[image]

## Solution 2:

yes can use react-native-svg for this purpose.

you can get your solution from my code. i hope this will 100% work for you.

[image]

```
import { Svg, Defs, Rect, Mask, Circle } from 'react-native-svg';
const WrappedSvg = () => (
    <View style={{ aspectRatio: 1 }}>
        <Svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <Defs>
                <Mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%">
                    <Rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="#fff" />
                    <Circle r="45" cx="50" cy="50" />
                </Mask>
            </Defs>
            <Rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="0" />
        </Svg>
    </View>
);

export class index extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>

                <View style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: 300, position: 'absolute' }}>
                    <WrappedSvg />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default index;
```

Comment: You can increase `viewBox` dimensions to fix pixelation.

Comment: I had to workaround this example quite a lot because it wasn't working. See the following snack for a working version: https://snack.expo.dev/vtF1puQvz

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I asked and answered here: [React native: transparent view inside opaque view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39883589/react-native-transparent-view-inside-opaque-view)
You can create `<View>` with transparent `backgroundColor` and non-transparent `borderColor`, then you set `borderRadius` and all sizes and voila

Answer (score -1):

You need to use some masked native views (iOs, Android) and wrap your content in it.
Like this:
[image]

Or you can use our small library https://github.com/ibitcy/react-native-hole-view